# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

i have started learning android not very long ago.. It has only been sometime when this error creeped in haunting me ever since. I am following tutorials to build a weather app named Sunshine. I have double checked the api and it looks good. i have also inherited the AsyncTask class to work on the background thread, overridden the doInBackground() and onPostExecute() method to return to my UI thread successfully(I suppose). I have checked my code ton of times but couldn't resolve the error.

```
05-20 01:10:04.036 28055-28154/com.example.android.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                          Process: com.example.android.sunshine, PID: 28055
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                              at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                              at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
                                                                              at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
                                                                              at com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(ForecastFragment.java:115)
                                                                              at com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:221)
                                                                              at com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:89)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
05-20 01:10:04.826 28055-28055/com.example.android.sunshine D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow05-20 01:15:04.106 28055-28154/com.example.android.sunshine I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28055 SIG: 9
```

forecastfragment file

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
        private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
        public ForecastFragment() {
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
                weatherTask.execute("110025");
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String[] data = {
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
                    "today-sunny - 41/29",
            };
            List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(
                    Arrays.asList(data));

            mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }

        public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
            private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

            public String getReadableDateString(long time) {
                Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
                return format.format(date).toString();
            }

    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int days) throws JSONException {
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        String[] resultStrs = new String[days];
        for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            JSONObject TemperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = TemperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = TemperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }
        for (String s : resultStrs) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "forecast entry:" + s);
        }
        return resultStrs;


    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
// so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

// Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;
        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int days = 7;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?&APPID=bab4c81d2c0f80d573a3c37211c3353e";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(days))
                    .build();
            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON string:" + forecastJsonStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            forecastJsonStr = null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, days);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null){
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for (String dayForecastStr : result){
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am a noob at this and it has been 2 days and i still couldn't trace the problem. All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you come around [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180721/2437227) ?

Comment: in doInBackground your `forecastJsonStr` is null. So when you call getWeatherDataFromJson with null value it's throwing an exception

Comment: I've called your URL. Your API KEY is wrong.

this is the response i got

`{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @AnupDasari hi mate, thanks.. I resolved my problem by initialising a string named q which equals the zip code of the place i am trying to fetch the data of, in my case it is 40497...then changed {.appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])} to {.appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, q)} but i don't think its the correct solution. help still required

Answer (score 0):

Did you get thr correct `forecastJsonStr` ? Maybe it's null;

I tried to access the url ,it's response like [this](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?&APPID=bab4c81d2c0f80d573a3c37211c3353e&q=null&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7)

What's your `Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON string:" + forecastJsonStr);` output?

Answer (score 0):

earlier my code was this

```
String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int days = 7;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?&APPID=bab4c81d2c0f80d573a3c37211c3353e";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(days))
                    .build();
```

furthermore i have declared a `string q = "110025"` as it was not initialised anywhere before and i passed it in the parameters of `.appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,q)` like this and voila, itworked.
now the code looks like

```
String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        q="110025";
        int days = 7;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?&APPID=bab4c81d2c0f80d573a3c37211c3353e";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, q)
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(days))
                    .build();
```

i think the problem was in the formation of the URL only where the value of q was not initialized before because of which there was a null pointer exception.